# latitude and longitude data from SQL Server and plot points using Leaflet

Tags: sql, coldfusion, leaflet

My question is essentially this:
How do I transform data from SQL Server and map it in Leaflet?
HINT: We are running Coldfusion 11, SQL Server 2000, Leaflet and JQuery if that helps in any way. If I need to download a javascript library I can easily do so.

I have ambulance and fire events in a database with xy coordinates. My goal is to query out the current events and place them on a Leaflet map. All of our ambulances and fire trucks have gps in them and they are constantly broadcasting their location and status. Here is my query for getting the latest gps data for each truck;

```
SELECT
DateTimeStamp
, RTRIM(CallSign) AS [CallSign]
, RTRIM(UnitStatus) AS [UnitStatus]
, Latitude
, Longitude
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), DateTimeStamp, 106) AS [CurrentDate]
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTimeStamp, 108) AS [CurrentTime]
FROM FireEMSGPSDatabase
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
  RTRIM(CallSign) AS [Ambulance]
, MAX(DateTimeStamp) AS [MostRecentTime]
FROM HISTORY_201506
WHERE RTRIM(CallSign) LIKE 'LCM__'
GROUP BY RTRIM(CallSign)
) 
AS [MostRecent] ON DateTimeStamp = MostRecent.MostRecentTime
ORDER BY RTRIM(CallSign) ASC*
```

Shown Below is a sample output from this query;

```
DateTimeStamp   CallSign    UnitStatus  Latitude    Longitude   CurrentDate CurrentTime
2015-06-04 17:14:17.357 LCM01   AQ  26.56428    -81.87044   04 Jun 2015 17:14:17
2015-06-04 17:14:17.357 LCM01   AQ  26.56428    -81.87044   04 Jun 2015 17:14:17
2015-06-04 17:14:18.670 LCM02   AQ  26.64074    -81.86507   04 Jun 2015 17:14:18
2015-06-04 17:14:34.420 LCM03   AR  26.64157    -81.90973   04 Jun 2015 17:14:34
2015-06-04 17:14:20.420 LCM04   TA  26.63885    -81.94159   04 Jun 2015 17:14:20
2015-06-04 17:14:21.297 LCM05   AQ  26.4377 -82.07806   04 Jun 2015 17:14:21
```

Shown below is my Coldfusion page with the leaflet map added in and the cfquery with cfoutput;

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<cfquery datasource="GPSDatabase" name="AmbulanceLocation">
SELECT
DateTimeStamp
, RTRIM(CallSign) AS [CallSign]
, RTRIM(UnitStatus) AS [UnitStatus]
, Latitude
, Longitude
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), DateTimeStamp, 106) AS [CurrentDate]
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTimeStamp, 108) AS [CurrentTime]
FROM FireEMSGPSDatabase
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
  RTRIM(CallSign) AS [Ambulance]
, MAX(DateTimeStamp) AS [MostRecentTime]
FROM HISTORY_201506
WHERE RTRIM(CallSign) LIKE 'LCM__'
GROUP BY RTRIM(CallSign)
)
AS [MostRecent] ON DateTimeStamp = MostRecent.MostRecentTime
ORDER BY RTRIM(CallSign) ASC
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="AmbulanceLocation">
<table>
<tr>
<td>#DateTimeStamp#</td>
<td>#CallSign#</td>
<td>#UnitStatus#</td>
<td>#Latitude#</td>
<td>#Longitude#</td>
<td>#CurrentDate#</td>
<td>#CurrentTime#</td>
</tr>
</table>
</cfoutput>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map', {center: [26.5641867068354,-81.8704100173261],fullscreenControl: true, zoom: 12});
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To sum it all up;

1. I have a query for SQL Server that extracts the latest xy coordinates of my ambulances.
2. I have a Coldfusion page that has a Leaflet map and the cfquery.

My question is how to map out the coordinates in a Leaflet map. 
Once again; I am using Coldfusion 11, SQL Server 2000, Leaflet and Jquery. The database is not spatialized - it is merely raw integers and character data.
This question is cross-posted on the Adobe Coldfusion forum, but I am re-posting here because so many people frequent this site.
I am not a javascripting or Coldfusion expert. If you can spell out your ideas precisely that would help me out a lot.

Comment: Thank you chipmunkofdoom2 for helping me with the editing of this post.

Comment: Which part of the whole process are you having a problem with? Given you've perhaps tried [something], how did it not "work"? What were your expectations, and how were they not met?